# Laravel error when trying call controller method inside component

Tags: php, laravel, view, components, laravel-blade

So basically I have this component called Datatable. Just trying to make a very simple form of table component for my application.

The errors seems to happen at the last step of the component file when I call the view.

My `index.blade.php` where I try to use the component like this:

```
<x-datatable fn="users" />
```

To clearify, the "fn" variable is the method I want to call in my Datatable component file.

My datatable component file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Datatable extends Component
{
    /**
     * The function/metho we want to get
     * data from at the datatable controller
     *
     * @var String
     */
    private $fn;

    /**
     * The controller used
     * DatatableController
     *
     * @var Controller
     */
    private $controller = \App\Http\Controllers\DatatableController::class;

    /**
     * This is all the data the table needs
     *
     * @var JSON 
    */
    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($fn)
    {
        $this->fn = $fn;
    }

    /**
     * Get the data in JSON format from the DataTable controller
     * based on the method given in the x-blade component
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function data()
    {
        $this->data = app()->call([$this->controller, $this->fn]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.datatable');
    }
}
```

The error I get is this:
`TypeError Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\View\Factory::startComponent() must be of the type array, null given, called in D:\Laragon\www\table-test\storage\framework\views\c3b84706f301f85254f4ebb5d2f86ff3d680d02b.php on line 5 (View: D:\Laragon\www\table-test\resources\views\index.blade.php)`

I have tried to clear the view cache but it just gives the same error.
When using `dd()` on `$this->data = app()->call([$this->controller, $this->fn]);` it shows me the data as it should.

The view that the component uses is empty, but it exists, so that should not be a problem there either.

What could cause this? Anyone seen something like this?

Comment: maybe you're calling the component somewhere else without the fn ? you can check directly the cache view file and right before the error line add manualy a dd().

Answer (score 0):

Remember that php uses camelcase, this means the class should called DataTable and you should be calling the component

```xml
<x-data-table fn="users"/>
```

Comment: That's not the error. The class is called "Datatable". There's nothing to camelcase.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "data" was a method already used by something in the back when using components. Renamed method to `getData()` instead, working now.